# How to modify style of individual items in QComboBox?

Tags: qt

Given a QComboBox widget, i can easily change style for drop-down list. Foe example, this style sheet adds green border for drop down list:

```
QComboBox QAbstractItemView { border: 5px solid green; }
```

[image]

But if i try to change style for individual items, it simply doesn't work:

```
QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item { border: 5px solid green; }
```

[image]

is it possible to change style for individual list items in QComboBox, or it's not supported?

Comment: Yup, you can do it. Check QAbstractItemDelegate. To use it just call QComboBox::setItemDelegate()

Comment: @Blood You make this an answer... As it's the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you can do it. All what you need is to use [QAbstractItemDelegate](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qabstractitemdelegate.html). To use it just call QComboBox::setItemDelegate()